# Selective XML parsing

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

This the xml file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bank>
      <Account type="saving">
            <Id>1001</Id>
            <Name>Jack Robinson</Name>
            <Amt>10000</Amt>
      </Account>
      <Account type="current">
            <Id>1002</Id>
            <Name>Sony Corporation</Name>
            <Amt>1000000</Amt>
      </Account>
</Bank>
```

I need to parse this xml and get the contents between `<Bank>...</Bank>`. My output xml should be

```
<Account type="saving">
            <Id>1001</Id>
            <Name>Jack Robinson</Name>
            <Amt>10000</Amt>
      </Account>
      <Account type="current">
            <Id>1002</Id>
            <Name>Sony Corporation</Name>
            <Amt>1000000</Amt>
      </Account>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this using Java?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials about XML parsing. Please walk yourself through some of them.

Comment: I am sorry. I see tutorials on how to extract individual elements. I would like to get the entire xml and store the output as an xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: 
your output XML is not valid XML.

XML must have root element which you try to remove.

As @Seelenvirtuose said, there are tons of ways to do what you want on many levels.

From simple manipulating original XML as String and up to using DOM model, JAXB, XPath/XQuery, or XSLT. It is matter of your choice.

As example with Apache commons utils:

```
String resultString = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(originalXMLString,"<Bank>","</Bank>").trim();
```

Of course your output can be only String, because it is not valid XML. Then you can do with that String whatever you want - print it, store in file or DB etc...